# MINGW32 + Makefile.am and Makefile.in

Tags: makefile, mingw

I've obtained some source code I want to compile. I'm pretty new to this...

I've got a couple Makefile.am's and Makefile.in's but cannot figure out how to use MINGW32 to compile. I've add mingw32 directory to my path and then cd'ing to the directory. From here I've used every combination of mingw32-make, ./configure, mingw32 -make but cannot get anything to work. I know people say there is information online, of which I've looked over for hours, but I'm still having difficulty. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion for you is to install [MSYS|MINGW](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS). It is fully integrated with Mingw32 and emulates a bash environment. The documentation in the website is enough to get things working. I successfully ported some *nix projects to Windows (both 32 and 64 bits) recently. Mount yout c:\ as /home/ and start working as you are at bash. As simple as that!